# dynamic row works without style

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have this little dynamic row program. I have a `label`, an `option box`, and `input text`. The number of `input texts` depends on the number in `option box`. It works well with out style but when I style the input, it doesn't work anymore and I don't get what I did wrong.

If i take away these codes

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css">
```

it runs smoothly but when i add it the input box doesnt work
here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>row</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css">
    <style type="text/css">

</style>
    <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
        $(window).load(function(){
        jQuery('.ui-select').delegate('select[name="radio-choice-1"]', 'change', function(event){
        var field_template = '<input type="text" name="row[]" /><br />';
        var howmany = parseInt(jQuery(this).val());
        var container = jQuery(this).parent('.ui-select').find('.form-dynamic-fields').empty();
        if (howmany > 0){
        for (i=1; i<=howmany; i++){
        container.append(jQuery('<div class="ui-select-row"><input type="text" name="rows[' + i +'][]" />'));
        }
        }
        });
        jQuery('.ui-select').delegate('select[name="rows_counts[]"]', 'change', function(event){
        var parent = jQuery(this).parent('.ui-select-row');
        parent.find('input[type="text"]').remove();
        var howmany = jQuery(this).val();
        var row_id = jQuery(this).attr('row-id');
        for (i=1; i<=howmany; i++){
        parent.prepend('<input type="text" name="rows[' + row_id + '][' + i + ']" />');
        }
        });
        });//]]>  
    </script>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="ui-select" id="rows" data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="rows" class="select" data-role="fieldcontain">Number Of Rows:</label>
            <select name="radio-choice-1" id="rows" data-native-menu="false"  tabindex="-1" data-role="fieldcontain" class="ui-field-contain ui-body ui-br" data-mini="true">               
                <option data-placeholder='true'>select number of rows</option>
                <option value="1">1 rows</option>
                <option value="2">2 rows</option>
                <option value="3">3 rows</option>
                <option value="4">4 rows</option>
            </select>
        <div class="form-dynamic-fields"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do learn to format your code before posting it online. Bad formatting turns people off from trying to help you, and will just skip to the next question.

Comment: sorry im trying to learn to do the proper formatting but when i copy it for eclipse and paste it on notepad++ it turned out like that i will edit it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you add mobile libraries:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.0-beta.1.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css">
```

Your html elements css will change according to above mentioned css. So, In your case your `select element` changed to `div` with class `ui-select`. Use

```
var container = jQuery(this).parent('.ui-select').siblings('.form-dynamic-fields').empty();
```

Instead of

```
var container = jQuery(this).parent('.ui-select').find('.form-dynamic-fields').empty();
```

Try:

```
jQuery('.ui-select').delegate('select[name="radio-choice-1"]', 'change', function(event){
    console.log("here");
    var field_template = '<input type="text" name="row[]" /><br />';
    var howmany = parseInt(jQuery(this).val());
    var container = jQuery(this).parent('.ui-select').siblings('.form-dynamic-fields').empty();
    if (howmany > 0){
        for (i=1; i<=howmany; i++){
            container.append(jQuery('<div class="ui-select-row"><input type="text" name="rows[' + i +'][]" />'));
        }
    }
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/P3DBx/)**</kbd>

Comment: your demo works really fine its what i wanted but why does the input text not having style anyway why does my own program not working i copied your code anyway lol..thank you hope others will be helped with this.

Comment: my mistake was with the number of braces i should start to learn how to format code properly so i dont get extra braces thanks